CDK Drag and drop preview is going behind the modal dialog
After going through many stack overflow answers I am posting this question. I have a requirement to enable drag-and-drop on the dialog modal. I am using this on the table rows. I can drag and drop the rows but the preview is always behind the modal. I have also come across this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-droplist-mat-dialog-solve?file=src%2Fstyles.css,angular.json,src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css but I don't see any difference in the code. Can anyone help me here? I am also attaching the screenshot for the same.
[cdkDragPreviewContainer]="parent" is not helpful since it is moving the preview to the extreme right (out of the screen)


  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    console.log('event::::', event);
    moveItemInArray(this.items, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    console.log("event.container.data[event.currentIndex]:::", event.container.data[event.currentIndex])
    if (event.container.data[event.currentIndex]['freeze'] === false) {
      if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
        moveItemInArray(
          event.container.data,
          event.previousIndex,
          event.currentIndex
        );
      } else {
        transferArrayItem(
          event.previousContainer.data,
          event.container.data,
          event.previousIndex,
          event.currentIndex
        );
      }
    }
  }
  .example-box {
    cursor: move;
  }
  
  .example-box.cdk-drag-disabled {
    cursor: default;
  }
  
  .cdk-drag-preview {
    background     : white;
    padding        : 20px 10px;
    color          : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    display        : flex;
    align-items    : center;
    font-size      : 14px;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
      0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      transform: translate(0);
  }
  
  .cdk-drag-placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .cdk-drag-animating {
    transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }
  
  .example-box:last-child {
    border: none;
  }
  
  .example-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .example-box:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
    transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }
  
<kyn-side-drawer [open]="open" size="md" titletext="Column Settings" labeltext="" 
    (on-close)="applyOrCancelChanges($event)" submitbtntext="Ok" cancelbtntext="Cancel">
    <kyn-global-filter>
        Show:
        <kyn-checkbox value="hiddencol"> Hidden Column </kyn-checkbox>
        <kyn-checkbox value="visiblecol"> Visible Column </kyn-checkbox>
    </kyn-global-filter>
    <kyn-table>
        <kyn-thead>
            <kyn-header-tr>
                <kyn-th>Visible</kyn-th>
                <kyn-th>Column</kyn-th>
                <kyn-th>Freeze</kyn-th>
            </kyn-header-tr>
        </kyn-thead>
        <kyn-tbody cdkDropList class="example-list" [cdkDropListData]="items" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let row of items">
                <kyn-tr [rowId]="row.id" [key]="row.id" [selected]="row.show" [locked]="row.freeze" [preventHighlight]="row.show" 
                [dimmed]="!row.show" [checkboxSelection]="true" class="example-box" cdkDrag [cdkDragDisabled]="row.freeze">

                    <kyn-td>{{row.data | translate}}</kyn-td>
                    <kyn-td>{{row.freeze}}</kyn-td>
                </kyn-tr>
            </ng-container>
        </kyn-tbody>
    </kyn-table>
</kyn-side-drawer>




The library you are using @kyndryl-design-system is working with shadow root, so you are getting difficulties applying CSS, a simple and easy fix to this problem is making it so that the root element, will be just the parent element
@Input('cdkDragPreviewContainer')

previewContainer: PreviewContainer


Configures the place into which the preview of the item will be inserted. Can be configured globally through CDK_DROP_LIST. Possible values:
global - Preview will be inserted at the bottom of the . The advantage is that you don't have to worry about overflow: hidden or z-index, but the item won't retain its inherited styles.


parent - Preview will be inserted into the parent of the drag item. The advantage is that inherited styles will be preserved, but it may be clipped by overflow: hidden or not be visible due to z-index. Furthermore, the preview is going to have an effect over selectors like :nth-child and some flexbox configurations.


ElementRef | HTMLElement - Preview will be inserted into a specific element. Same advantages and disadvantages as parent.

            <kyn-tr
                [rowId]="row.id"
                [key]="row.id"
                [selected]="true"
                [locked]="false"
                [checkboxSelection]="true"
                class="example-box"
                cdkDrag
                cdkDragPreviewContainer="parent"
            >
                <kyn-td>{{ row.id }}</kyn-td>
                <kyn-td>{{ row.name }}</kyn-td>
            </kyn-tr>

Stackblitz Demo

The overlay has more z-index that the drag item, we can simply set a higher z-index to solve the issue!
z-index -> tells the browser which element has the priority to be layed over the another, think of elements as paper stacked on top of another, from top to bottom of element traversal, z-index can be used to override this stacking!
.cdk-drag-preview {
    background     : white;
    padding        : 20px 10px;
    color          : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    display        : flex;
    align-items    : center;
    font-size      : 14px;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
      0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      transform: translate(0);
    z-index: 2000 !important; /* Kindly tune this value so that it works best, start with a really high value and then reduce! */
  }


I have already tried this. Not working

@Amir try increasing the z-index to a very high number? also make sure its display is block!

I tried with display: block and z-index: 99999 !important but unfortunately not working

@Amir please replicate the issue in stackblitz and share!

Hey pls check now
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16-starter-h2zuak?file=package.json,src%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fside-drawer%2Fside-drawer.component.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css,src%2Fside-drawer%2Fside-drawer.component.html,tsconfig.json,src%2Fside-drawer%2Fside-drawer.component.css
It is going behind

@Amir updated my answer! please check my stackblitz

Hey Can you pls share the link here. I don't see any changes. It still goes behind

Please try dragging towards the left of the modal.

try maximizing the screen and then drag the item. It is going toward the extreme left. I already tried the above solution

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

could you please point me to the line of code which you are suggesting?
Did you try expanding the browser window of Slackbitz? The preview goes towards the extreme right.

I have already tried the piece of code shared by you before posting this question. The z-index issue gets solved but the preview is not in the correct position. It is going out of the window.
